# Angular | Directive not passing correct value back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

Hi i have created a directive and it does not pass back the correct message.

The directive is used to pass tool-tips back to the html page

this is what the html looks like

```
<info-text info-msg="Adding another applicant might help you to get approved."></info-text>
```

below is the directive

```
(function(){

angular.module('mainApp').directive('infoText', [function () {
    return {
        scope: { infoMessage: '&infoMsg' },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<p class="info-text"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> {{infoText}}</p>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $(elem).prev().hover(function(){
                $(elem).addClass('info-hover');
            }, function(){
                $(elem).removeClass('info-hover');
            });
        }
    };
}]);

}());
```

the message i get rendered on the page is as follows (it does send the glyphicon):

```
{{infoText}}
```

Any ideas,

thanks. Kieran.

Comment: That usually means angular has fallen over causing the bunbound value to be rendered. Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `&` for this sort of binding, basically it is used for expression binding. I think one way binding (`@`) is efficient for what you are doing.

Also you should change directive template `{{infoText}}` to `{{infoMessage}}`

**Markup**

```
<info-text 
   info-msg="{{'Adding another applicant might help you to get approved.'}}"></info-text>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('mainApp').directive('infoText', [function () {
    return {
        scope: { infoMessage: '@infoMsg' },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<p class="info-text"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> {{infoMessage}}</p>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $(elem).prev().hover(function(){
                $(elem).addClass('info-hover');
            }, function(){
                $(elem).removeClass('info-hover');
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And making more cleaner and readable html you could place that string into some scope variable and pass that scope variable in `info-msg` attribute

Comment: Another tip is to not re-key info-msg to infoMessage .  If you keep it the same name its more maintainable (easier to follow) .

Comment: @Nix correct.. but sometimes having attribute alias is better thing(when variable will have bigger name)

Comment: I'd argue that you should pick the best name for it and stick to it.  But it comes down to preference / coding standards i guess.  cheers.

Comment: @Nix very true.. there is no harm with both, As I said I'll prefer to go for alias for bigger name to increase the readability of html, to read html in single line.(on that your point is correct which will increase the efforts in maintainability). Thanks & cheers :)